# How do I get the MAC address of LoRa nodes?

Tags: lora

I have some LoRa nodes (a Dragino LoRa Shield to append an Arduino Uno) and I want to connect them with a Dragino Gateway LG01-P.

I need to take the MAC address (unique address) of my nodes but I don't know how can do that. How can I solve this?

Comment: This is usually done at protocol level with a unique ID (and often secret) *programmed by you* into the MCU running your node.  Since you haven't given any details of that, this is unanswerable.